# Update Javascript variable setInterval in an object created by function with

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, object, timing

Im trying to create a stop and start timer function in javascript for use in jQuery to record the time between a .focus() and .blur() of a $('input').

This is what I have so far:

```
function startTimer() {

    _id = guid()
    time = 0
    timer_id = setInterval(function () {
        time++;
    }, 100);

    timer = {
        _id: _id,
        time: time,
        timer_id: timer_id,
    }

    return timer;
}

function stopTimer(timer) {
    var stop = timer.time
    clearInterval(timer.timer_id);
    return stop;
}

// usage
fieldTimes = {}


// on focus of field
$("input").on('focus', function (e) {

    element = e.target;
    var timer = startTimer();

    // on unfocus of field
    $(element).blur(function () {
        var time = stopTimer(timer);
        var field = e.target.id
        if (fieldTimes.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
            fieldTimes[field] += time;
        } else {
            fieldTimes[field] = time;
        }
    })

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewblaney/Ltfvmaec/

The problem is that time is not being updated on the timer object created by startTimer

Comment: @AndrewBlaney - pay attention to your variable names/declarations. You use globals `time` and `timer` in `startTimer` and local `timer` and `time` in `focus` and `blur` handlers.

Comment: @AndrewBlaney - you add a new `blur` handler to an input every time its `focus` handler executes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say:

```
timer = {
    _id: _id,
    time: time,
    timer_id: timer_id,
}
```

All the values on the right-hand side are being *evaluated*. Thus, `timer.time` is set to the integer value that `time` was at that point in time. It is *not* set as a reference to the `time` variable.

One fix is to simply reference `timer.time` in the interval:

```
timer_id = setInterval(function () {
    timer.time++;
}, 100);
```

Edit:
Also, you need to unbind the `.blur` event you're attaching:

```
$(element).on("blur.timer", function () {
    // ... code here ...
    $(element).off("blur.timer");
})
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ltfvmaec/5/)**

Comment: Thank you, the problem was timer.time++ has made it work how I expected, my jquery seems to be fine though, I'm not sure what blur.timer is referring to

Comment: @AndrewBlaney The `.timer` part of `blur.timer` is just an [event namespace](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/). I added it so that any other blur events on the object won't be removed, only the blur events with the namespace timer.

Answer (score 0):

You are just increasing timer variable not time object.Just change your to below

```
timer_id = setInterval(function () {
    timer.time = time++; 
}, 100);
```